# JQuery animate() isn't animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to animate a sidebar to come onto the screen once the user has clicked the menu toggle button.

There are no errors in the console, and it is definitely firing when the menu button is clicked as I put an `alert()` function there which does execute. Despite this, the sidebar doesn't ever appear on the screen.

Here's the code:

Sidebar

```
<div class="sidebarContainer"
    style="width: 15em; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: -300px; background-color: #333; z-index: 999; overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="titleContainer"
        style="text-align: center; padding-top: 2rem; padding-bottom: 1rem; background-color: #222;">
        <img style="width: 6rem; height: 6rem; border-radius: 50px;"
            src="/images/users/icons/{{ Auth::user()->icon_path }}">
        <br><br>
        <span style="color: white;">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
    </div>

    @foreach($Menus as $menu)
    <div id="linkContainer" class="linkContainer" style="padding: 0.3rem;">
        <a style="text-decoration: none; color: white; padding-left: 0.3rem;" href="/{{ $menu->slug }}">{!!
            $menu->icon_path !!} {{ $menu->name }}</a>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    <div id="linkContainer" class="linkContainer" style="padding: 0.3rem;">
        <a style="text-decoration: none; color: white; padding-left: 0.3rem;" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
            onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><i
                class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>

        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @CSRF
        </form>
    </div>

    <br><br>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#linkContainer:nth-child(odd)").css('background-color', '#222');
    });

    $("#menuToggle").click(function(){
        $("#sidebarContainer").animate({"left": "0px"});
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the sidebarContainer ID, but the div only has the sidebarContainer class. I updated the code to also put the click within your function call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#linkContainer:nth-child(odd)").css('background-color', '#222');


    $("#menuToggle").click(function(){
        $(".sidebarContainer").animate({"left": "0px"});
    });

});
</script>
```

on a different note you are most likely duplicating IDS in this loop and IDs are meant to be unique:

```
@foreach($Menus as $menu)
    <div id="linkContainer" class="linkContainer" style="padding: 0.3rem;">
```

Comment: Yes the IDs are duplicated as it creates the element per menu item I will change that. Bit of a face palm moment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sideContainerbar is positioned in your css and probably has a value for left property  also in you css. The left property only works on positioned elements. (Relative or absolute), or you can include the position relative to the object you are supplying as argument to the animate function. #cheers

Comment: It already is?

`<div class="sidebarContainer"
    style="width: 15em; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: -300px; background-color: #333; z-index: 999; overflow: scroll;">`

Comment: Ok now try this wrap the script you have inside $(document).ready(function(){ YOUR-CODE-GOES-HERE}); it should be fine now